# Bash create file script with echo command

Tags: bash

I need to generate the following file content with the bash script.

```
#!/bin/sh
script_dir=$(dirname "$(realpath $0)")
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$script_dir/lib
exec $script_dir/{EXEC_FILE_WITH_EXT}
```

i.e. something like

> my_script_generator.sh

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "<filecontent above>" > new_script.sh
```

The problem's a make all screening correctly to avoid echo evaluate the content and put it just as is.
For the more huge script, it becomes a problem.

Is there an online service that simplifies that work?

Comment: You are using `bash` or POSIX `sh`?

Comment: Also `{EXEC_FILE_WITH_EXT}` will be converted as a literal string i.e. why isn't there a preceding `$` if its a variable?

Comment: `problem's a make all screening correctly to avoid echo evaluate the content and put it just as is` What is "screening"? `Is there an **online** service` How did you go from "evaluating echo" to an "online service"? Why do you need an online service? What you want is a __templating__ system - there are many templating engines available. Basically, you want to just to _substitute_ the `{EXEC...}` part with some other thing _in your template_?

Comment: If OP wants to expand `EXEC_FILE_WITH_EXT` to a real executable name, then I do not agree with the duplicate. Duplicate is about multiline strings - without expansions in inside the string, without templating part. @nen777w please clarify your question.

Comment: @KamilCuk: Agreed, feel free to remove the dupe in that case, but I think its just a typo on their side, missing out `$`

Comment: You can use the accepted answer with `<<'EOM'` instead of `<<EOM`

Answer (score 1):

Use cat+here-document and backslash before $ signs you dont't want to be evaluated.

```sh
#!/bin/sh

cat > new_script.sh <<EOF
#!/bin/sh
script_dir=\$(dirname "\$(realpath \$0)")
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=\$script_dir/lib
exec \$script_dir/{EXEC_FILE_WITH_EXT}
EOF
```

A script like this (not bullet proof) could help automate the task

```sh
#!/bin/sh

# make-script.sh
# input : a sequence of commands
# output : sequence of commands which generates a copy of the source script file
echo "cat <<EOF"
echo "#!/bin/sh"
echo

sed "s/\\\$/\\\\\\\$/g" 
echo "EOF"
```